# Calling Office 365 APIs on behalf of another user

Tags: api, rest, office365, onedrive

I am developing a web application for Office 365 for business. I authorize it with my admin account. So I have access token for calling REST APIs on behalf of admin user.

Is there a way to call APIs on behalf of another user inside my organization?
Or is there any other way to get the list of another user's files in OneDrive?

Comment: Perhaps this would help
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2014/04/15/calling-o365-apis-from-your-web-api-on-behalf-of-a-user.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the app only token to access data belonging to other users.
Please follow the steps [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2015/01/21/building-demon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage) to register the app and then follow [these](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2015/02/10/client-credentials-flow-for-mail-api-in-python.aspx) to get the required token

Comment: Yes, you are right. But Microsoft did not support app only tokens for Sharepoint back in March. They have added this support few weeks ago.